# What did I miss that my RXJS service doesn't return array?

Tags: angular, rxjs

For my todo app I've followed this blog post to implement a service to share data to my components: https://dev.to/avatsaev/simple-state-management-in-angular-with-only-services-and-rxjs-41p8

It is currently working but not the way it is intended (at least as far as I can tell).

Service:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class TodoListService {

    showCompleted = false;

    @Input() toDoData = {taskName: '', extraNote: '', taskCompleted: false, dueDate: Date};

    constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {
        this.getToDos();
    }

    private readonly todoListSource = new BehaviorSubject<ToDo[]>([]);

    readonly todos$ = this.todoListSource.asObservable().pipe(
        shareReplay(1)
    );

    readonly completedToDos$ = this.todos$.pipe(
        shareReplay(1),
        map(todos => this.todos.filter(todo => todo.taskCompleted))
    );

    get todos(): ToDo[] {
        return this.todoListSource.getValue();
    }

    set todos(val: ToDo[]) {
        this.todoListSource.next(val);
    }


    getToDos() {
        this.todoService.getToDos()
            .subscribe((data: []) => {
                console.log('TodoModel List get Todos Service: ', data);
                this.todos = data;
            });
    }

    addToDo() {
        this.todoService.addToDo(this.toDoData)
            .subscribe((result) => {
                /*console.log(result);*/
            });

    }

    deleteToDo(id) {
        this.todoService.deleteToDo(id)
            .subscribe(res => {
                    this.getToDos();
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
    }

    completed(id, todo) {
        todo.taskCompleted = !todo.taskCompleted;
        this.todoService.updateToDo(id, todo)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.getToDos();
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let todo of todoListService.todos$">
    <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar>
            <mat-icon [ngClass]="todo.taskCompleted ? 'green' : 'red' ">thumb_up</mat-icon>

        </div>
        <mat-card-title>{{todo.taskName}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>
            <mat-icon style="font-size: 15px">calendar_today</mat-icon>
            {{todo.dueDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
        <p>
            {{todo.extraNote}}
        </p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions align="center">
        <button mat-button (click)="todoListService.completed(todo.id, todo)">
            <mat-icon *ngIf="!todo.taskCompleted">done</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="todo.taskCompleted">close</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-button (click)="openDialog(todo)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-button (click)="todoListService.deleteToDo(todo.id)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

As far I understood I'm supposed to only use the readonly methods like `todos$` or `completedToDos$` to display the data as they can't modify the data. To be able to modify the data I have methods like `getToDos` etc.

Well I thought everything is great and I understood it, well apparently I did not. When I try to get all todo items in the html I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck
```

So it doesn't return an array as I expected.

If I change the `*ngFor` it works fine but as I understood not how it is supposed to be used.

```
<mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let todo of todoListService.todos">
```

Where did I go wrong or what didn't I understand?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: todoListService.todos$ is an observable

in the example you're following you'll notice they access this with: `todoListService.todos$ | async`

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: Thanks, when I read it I thought it is just a async process...